# RadAutoCompleteBox the given key was not present in the dictionary issue IE

Tags: internet-explorer, telerik

I have one issue in `telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox` control in IE.

Problem is that:

When I try to set a selected value from autocomplete dropdown. Just after its selection the cursor moves down between the present and the preceding textbox.
On typing during the selection it gives the below alert:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found the solution.**
you have to set the **height** of that **input** element or you can set **display:none** on your selection operation.

$("#<%= YourID.ClientID %>_Input").attr("style", "display: none !important;")